# Using a RAID Controller as Pass-thru vs RAID0

Tags: linux, raid, hardware-raid, dell-perc, passthrough

I have a server with DellPerc H750 Storage controller.

I want to use the controller as Pass-thru/Non-RAID  but I have the below questions:

A) Is it possible in the future to replace the controller with a HBA one without losing data ?

B) If I used the RAID0 configuration for each disk independently instead of the pass-thru config , would that lead to a better performance or not ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question A, yes. If you just do straight passthrough of the disks with *NO* RAID, then they are just disks and you could later change it to an HBA and it would be no different.

To answer question B, there are a few concepts being confused here. RAID0 takes many drives and stripes data across them to improve performance. You wouldn't have RAID 0 on a single disk.

Pass through is no RAID at all.